# java.lang.NumberFormatException is thrown for the string "008949679851"

Tags: java, string, integer

The following code `throws NumberFormatException` and I don't understand why,

```
String sku = "008949679851";
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(sku));
```

Interestingly, if I remove the first three digits and the keep the input string as "949679851", then this exception is not thrown. Is there a limit in length when converting a string to an integer value..? How can I make it work with the full string..?

Comment: Besides the number to big: also remember that having the 0 prefix in a literal means: **octal** number. So depending on what you want to do (or what you expect that number to be, it might be better to remove those 0s first).

Comment: I'll be sure to keep that in mind :)

Comment: `valueOf(String)` (without optional second radix argument) always parses in base 10 ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-)), regardless of leading zeros.  So it's not failing because of the non-octal digits 8 and 9, it just that the number is too doggone big for an `Integer`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the max value of an Integer is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` = `2147483647` and your number is greater than this `8949679851`. Instead use `Long.valueOf(sku)` or `BigInteger` for example:

```
Long l = Long.valueOf(sku);//Max value equal to 9223372036854775807

BigInteger b = new BigInteger(sku);
```

Comment: I think Kevin Anderson clarified that with his comment up at the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

In Java the maximum value for int and Integers is 2^31-1 (2147483647) so your number exceeds that value.

Comment: Thank you...!!! I understood it now and I am handling it accordingly to fit my need :).

Answer (score 1):

Java integer size is 32 bits (range -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647). `"008949679851"` is too long, while  `"949,679,851"` is within the range.